# Regex: how to extract a JSESSIONID cookie value from cookie string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I might receive the following cookie string.
`hello=world;JSESSIONID=sdsfsf;Path=/ei`

I need to extract the value of `JSESSIONID`

I use the following pattern but it doesn't seem to work. However `https://regex101.com` shows it's correct.

```
Pattern PATTERN_JSESSIONID = Pattern.compile(".*JSESSIONID=(?<target>[^;\\n]*)");
```

Comment: The regex could be better, but I guess your problem is with java's regex API because [it works fine for me](https://ideone.com/Gc7zN8)

Comment: How do you receive this string? Most things that handle http also deal with cookies for you.

Comment: @pvg I use http://square.github.io/retrofit/ and it's not that easy with it.

Comment: @user1745356 `java.net.HttpCookie.parse` parses cookie headers.

Comment: @pvg this is awesome. If you post your answer, I'll mark it as accepted. BTW my regex worked fine I just used matcher.matches() instead of matcher.find()

Comment: @user1745356 This answer is maybe not that great as it appears that method is somewhat too strict in some cases. But I still think the correct answer (especially given the many slightly inaccurate regexes provided, included yours) is 'use the underlying HTTP library'. If you google about you'll see 'cookies and retrofit' and especially 'cookies and okhttp' come up frequently with multiple extensive examples, particularly for auth/session cookies. Take a look at those or post a new question that's specifically about that since 'regex for matching JSESSIONID' is not really what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

You can reach your goal with a simpler approach using regex `(^|;)JSESSIONID=(.*);`. Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGvfe4/3) on Regex101 (you have forgotten to link the regular expression using the **save** button). Take a look on the following code. You have to extract the matched values using the class `Matcher`:

```
String cookie = "hello=world;JSESSIONID=sdsfsf;Path=/ei";
Pattern PATTERN_JSESSIONID = Pattern.compile("(^|;)JSESSIONID=(.*);");
Matcher m = PATTERN_JSESSIONID.matcher(cookie);
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output value:

> sdsfsf

Of course the result depends on the all of possible variations of the input text. The snippet above will work in every case the value is between `JSESSIONID` and `;` characters.

Comment: This also matches things like 'OJSESSIONID', etc, which is maybe not optimal if you really want the value of an actual session cookie.

Comment: @pvg You are right, thank you for the hint. `(^|;)` in the beginning would solve the issue.

Comment: I have found that I needed to change `(^|;)` to `(^|.*;)`, and `(.*)` matches everything including the semicolon, so you will need to be stricter and use something like  `([A-Z0-9]+)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can try below regex:

```
JSESSIONID=([^;]+)
```

[regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yRDrR6/3/)

```
String cookies = "hello=world;JSESSIONID=sdsfsf;Path=/ei;submit=true";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\bJSESSIONID=([^;]+)");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(cookies);
boolean found = matcher.find();
System.out.println("Sesssion ID: " + (found ? matcher.group(1): "not found"));
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/PRaWtN)

Answer (score 2):

You can even get what you aiming for with Splitting and Replacing the string aswell, below I am sharing which is working for me.

```
String s = "hello=world;JSESSIONID=sdsfsf;Path=/ei";

List<String> sarray = Arrays.asList(s.split(";"));

String filterStr = sarray.get(sarray.indexOf("JSESSIONID=sdsfsf"));
System.out.println(filterStr.replace("JSESSIONID=", ""));
```

Comment: What if cookies contain only one entry as `String cookies = "JSESSIONID=sdsfsf"` ?

Comment: While writing this example I believe cookies contain other entry as well along with JSEESIONID, few default entries will be there like user-agent info and other header details.

Comment: Such assumption makes your code less flexible. Another issue is `JSESSIONID` value is different for each client.